# How do I add "Recovery Console" and "User Defined Session" in the login menu?

Tags: 11.10, lightdm

Ubuntu 11.10 was loaded without a hitch however to obtain Classic Fallback I followed the following instructions -
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/08/return-to-ubuntu-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-11-10/

Log on Menu now shows

- Gnome Classic
- Gnome Classic(No effects)
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu 2D

"Recovery Console" and "User Defined Session" are NOT options - I can't remember if those options were available before entering Fallback command. How can I obtain these two options on Menu ? Please note my last comment - maybe all is well ?

Comment: I have come across several links to logon screens which are similar to mine - ie Without "Recovery Console" and "User Defined Session" as options - I simply don't know which is normal - My installation was a fresh install with a 4 user /home partition.

Comment: Are you confused with the *Recovery mode* which would just drop you to a root shell? That is a boot option of GRUB and cannot be added to the login menu.

Comment: Hi Lekensteyn - The answer supplied by Matus below did the trick. "Recovery Console" and "User Defined Session" are now options on my logon menu. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing package "gdm" and setting "lightdm" as default login manager works for me. Looks like gdm adds those two settings wanted.

Comment: Thanks @Matus -That solved the problem. "Recovery Console" and "User Defined Session" are now options in my logon page. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @GeoffSmith You can mark this question as solved by pressing the green button on the left of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this without installing `gdm`.

The login choices are .desktop files in `/usr/share/xesssions`.  The "Recovery Console" is a text file named `xterm.desktop` with contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Recovery Console
Comment=Failsafe session with only xterm
Exec=xterm
TryExec=xterm
Icon=
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gdm
```

and the "User Defined Session" is a text file named `xsession.desktop` with contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=User Defined Session
Comment=Custom ~/.xsession script
Exec=default
```

You can add these without `gdm`.  I did not add the "User Defined Session" so don't actually know that it works.

Comment: Sweet.  I'm so glad you put this here.  I was looking for a way to add a weird custom window manager login option.  This was exactly the data I needed to find.  I'm thinking on opening another question - then voting to close it in this direction myself, just to get a meaningful flagpost that is more easily searchable.